# Let $M$ be a $F[x]$-module. then $M\cong F[x]/(p(x))$ where $(p(x))$ maximal.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M$ be a $F[x]$-module. then $M\cong F[x]/(p(x))$ where $(p(x))$ maximal.

Here $F$ is a field. Is this statement true?

I think a map $f:M\to F[x]/(p)$ defined by $f(v_n)=x^n+(p)$, where $v_n$'s are basis elements, $n=0,1,\cdots,d-1$ ($d=\deg p$) may be the isomorphism, but here we need $\dim M=d$ to map all the basis elements and it seems like a circular reasoning.

Comment: The $K[X]$-module $K[X]^2$ will certainly not be isomorphic to a quotient of $K[X]$. In general, given arbitrary ring $A$ and a *simple* left $A$-module $S$, the latter will necessarily be isomorphic to a quotient of the form $A/I$, where $I$ is a *maximal* left ideal. In the particular case of the commutative ring $K[X]$ (the field $K$ being assumed commutative), all ideals are principal and consequently maximal ideals coincide with non-zero prime ideals and are generated by *irreducible* polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. For example, $F[x]$ viewed as a module of itself is not of this form. Neither is the module $F[x]/(x^2)$ (the ideal $(x^2)$ is not maximal, since $x^2$ is not an irreducible polynomial).

The modules of the form $F[x]/(p(x))$ with $(p(x))\subset F[x]$ a maximal ideal are precisely the *simple* modules.

Comment: If $M$ is simple, can $p(x)$ has degree more than $2$?

Comment: That depends on the field. $F[x]/(p(x))$ is maximal $\Leftrightarrow$ $(p(x))\subset F[x]$ is a maximal ideal $\Leftrightarrow$ $p(x)\in F[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial (over $F$). So if $F$ is algebraically closed then $\deg p = 1$ and if $F$ is real closed (e.g. $F=\mathbb{R}$) then $\deg p = 1$ or $2$. But for other fields, $p$ may have any degree. For example, the polynomial $p(x) = x^n - 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ for any $n\ge2$.

Comment: Why $\deg p=1$ or $2$ when $F=\mathbb{R}$?